# Scaring Pigeons - by remote control

Tags: pest-control

I have a problem with pigeons waking me in the early hours of the morning and I want to be able to scare them away from the comfort of my own bed with a press of a button.

There are a number of trees surrounding my garden and the pigeons will land in one of them from around 5am and call loudly to each other across the area. Ideally, I want something small that I can place in a tree and that won't need maintenance too often.

The local population of pigeons know that I am to be feared, so I only have to make the merest noise to scare them away - I also don't want a noise so load that it will disturb my neighbours.

So, I've assumed that it will be electronic - but if you have something more creative, please suggest it.

I'm not necessarily looking for a cheap solution - but it does have to be minimal effort, so no suggestions that start, "Using an Arduino..." please.

Comment: So, there are these things called pellet guns...

Comment: @JoshL1516 Don't think I haven't thought about it! The relative peace that I have at the moment is a result of me patrolling the garden multiple times per day - with a catapult. But the wily creatures are now very aware that they are difficult to hit - and it's just a sting when I do hit them. They give me the bird equivalent of the the finger (the bird?) and hop to another branch where they are even more difficult to hit. Apart from air guns being expensive, they are also problematic due to the surrounding gardens and houses in all directions.

Comment: What if you did something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Hoont-Repeller-Solar-Powered-Motion-Activated-Squirrels/dp/B081K7JCH5/ref=sr_1_21?crid=2R390B5P8S2PQ&keywords=motion+sensor+battery+powered+bird&qid=1663080950&sprefix=motion+sensor+battery+powered+bird%2Caps%2C147&sr=8-21

Comment: I've have a neighbor who uses one of these for deer. Not sure what the brand is, but its something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to provide electrical power to the desired location and it's USA based, the BN_Link series of products may be of use. There may be other manufacturers of products of this sort.

It's a module into which one connects an appliance of any sort. The electrical outlet can be triggered by an app on one's telephone at the touch of a finger.

Additionally, one can set schedules, the basis of which the device will power on and power off.

One of the products is an [outdoor-rated three outlet unit](https://www.bn-link.com/collections/wifi-outlets/products/bn-link-outdoor-smart-wi-fi-outlet-with-3-sockets-individually-controlled-outlets-compatible-with-alexa-and-google-home). I'm not a representative, but I am a satisfied user.

[image: bn_link 3 outlet outdoor device]

This would, of course, require that you find an additional device to provide the necessary distraction/dispersal, to match the power source. It also requires wifi signal at the location of the power block.

Comment: A nice idea - but 1) I'm in the UK, 2) there is no wi-fi near the (main) tree 3) there is no power near any of the trees, 4) what do I plug into it? I have some simple remote sockets that would work in place of this, but I still have the problem of having to permanently wire mains voltage to at least one of the trees,

Answer (score 1):

Deploy a hawk kite similar to this, like farmers do.

[image]

While it can't work in the tree itself, if you can mount it somewhere strategic, this may prevent the pigeons approaching anyway.

In the same vein, perhaps you can put hawk effigies on some of the tree branches.

Comment: This would probably work for a short time - but in my experience they quickly learn that it isn't to be feared. I tried a plastic owl some years ago, having been told they are the best solution. It worked for about 4 days. I do realise these work on farms so it would be nice to work out a way to use one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with these but it seems to fit your criteria.

https://worldbirds.com/ultrasound-bird-repeller/

Comment: *"The model is an ultrasonic bird deterrent that works not just on birds, but on other animal species, too. For example cats, dogs, chipmunks, raccoons, squirrels, and mice."* - This might additionally drive the asker's and neighbour's pets crazy at that 5AM window, and indirectly wake up a lot more people :)